# Replace blocks of text conditionally in R

Tags: r, string

I would like to replace blocks of text conditionally depending of internal results in a R run. Let's assume that I will import a template such as `teXt`:

```
lines <- tempfile(fileext = ".data")
cat("
We have a (positive)1 (negative)2 number.
", file=lines, sep = "\n")
teXt <- readLines(lines)
```

In this text we have possibilities, 1-positive and 2-negative. Assuming that I have a positive number I tried to use:

```
teXt  <- stringr::str_replace_all(teXt, " (negative)2", "") ## Exclude negative string possibility
teXt    <-  stringr::str_replace_all(teXt, " (positive)1", "positive") ## make positive the word in the final text
```

However, the replacement do not follow what I expect, i.e. did not produce the sentence "We have a positive number" and maintain the original template text. I tried to use `*words*` instead `(words)` but also did not work. I wonder if we have functions in R to perform such a task in a smarter (and workable!) way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your attempt to work you have to escape the special characters (opening and closing brackets)

```
teXt <- stringr::str_replace_all(teXt, "\\(negative\\)2", "") 
teXt <-  stringr::str_replace_all(teXt, "\\(positive\\)1", "positive")
```

---

Assuming you have a positive number a simplified(?) approach would be to remove round brackets along with text inside it and replace it with `"positive"`.

```
stringr::str_replace_all(teXt, "\\(.*\\)\\d+", "positive")
#[1] ""                               "    We have a positive number." "    "
```

Or using `gsub` in base R

```
gsub("\\(.*\\)\\d+", "positive", teXt)
```

You can wrap the output in `trimws` if you want to remove leading and lagging whitespace.